# mapDispatchToProps is not putting my function into props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React with Redux and following a tutorial, but I cannot for the life of me figure out this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.fetchPosts is not a function

I have a src file with actions/index.js and I have a components/posts_index.js file. As far as I can tell, these are the only two files involved in this error, and I do not believe mapDispatchToProps is actually putting my function in this.props, but I don't know why.

components/posts_index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import fetchPosts from '../actions/index';

class PostsIndex extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>List of Blog Posts</div>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchPosts }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostsIndex);
```

actions/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_POSTS = 'FETCH_POSTS';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api';
const API_KEY = '?key=hn8y9e7yhvjkw9w887';

export function fetchPosts () {
  const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`);

  return {
    type: FETCH_POSTS,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of :

```
export function fetchPosts () {....
```

Try:

```
 export default function fetchPosts () {..
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you. I'm a little confused, since I called import { fetchPosts } from ..., shouldn't it find fetchPosts anyway?

Comment: When you use default for the function , it knows what to import so no brackets needed then.

Answer (score 2):

In actions/index.js, change to export default

```js
export default function fetchPosts () {
  const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`);

  return {
    type: FETCH_POSTS,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

or edit import statement in your components/posts_index.js

```js
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/index';
```

Answer (score 0):

in index.js change your import from scoped

do this
`import PostsIndex  from "./Components/posts_index";`

instead of this `import { PostsIndex } from "./Components/posts_index";`