# mapDispatchToProps isn't connecting function to props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm using React-Redux with typescript and am trying to access a function defined in mapDispatchToProps, however I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getStoreList is not a function
>     at t.componentDidMount

The two files involved are container.tsx and mapper.ts. I've tried putting the contents of mapper.ts into container.tsx in case it was an issue with importing, however that doesn't fix the error.

The scenario is very similar to this previous stackoverflow question: [mapDispatchToProps is not putting my function into props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195773/mapdispatchtoprops-is-not-putting-my-function-into-props) however the solution doesn't seem to apply to my situation.

container.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps } from "./mapper";
import { IStoreListComponentProps } from './component';

export interface IStoreListContainerProps extends IStoreListComponentProps {
    fetchStoreList?: () => void;
}

export class StoreListContainer extends React.Component<IStoreListContainerProps> {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchStoreList();
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Example</div>;
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StoreListContainer);
```

mapper.ts

```
import { fetchStoreList } from "./actions/fetch-store-list";
import { IState } from "../../features/store/model";

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
    return {
        getStoreList: () => { dispatch(fetchStoreList()); },
    };
};

export const mapStateToProps = (state: IState) => {
    return {
        storeList: state.storeList
    };
};
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: `"fetchStoreList" !== "getStoreList"`

Answer (score -1):

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
    return {
        getStoreList: () => dispatch(fetchStoreList()),
    };
};
```

try writing it this way